# Need help getting a response from API

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest

I formulated this XHR request by converting it from curl.
The curl request works but can't get this one working. Please help.

```js
var url = "https://networkappers.com/api/port.php?ip=172.217.13.238&port=80";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Referer", "https://www.networkappers.com/tools/open-port-checker");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Look in the network tab. You have CORS issues

Comment: I'm aware of the CORS issues, I don't know how to fix them

Comment: Write a proxy and use your curl

Comment: ah how? I tried using CORS Anywhere proxy but its no longer up. anyway to bypass CORS?, trying to make this code useable to anyone that wants it, without any nodejs or other bs just running in html/javascript

Comment: You have a server. Use curl on the server, call the server with the parameters